# Why dont we just use lite-server alone instead of Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular, gulp

Gulp compile TS to JS when changes detected.
Lite-server compile TS to JS when changes detected too.
so, why people still choose Gulp?

Answer (score 0):

> why people still choose Gulp

Not all do. E.g. I don't. I just use webpack with ts-loader.

That said, gulp is a build tool for a more complete chain e.g. bundling css etc. Nothing stoping you from writing all that code your self or ofloading to some other tool (like webpack which is what I do) or grunt or just use gulp with the gulp ecosystem.

Again, you don't have to